# Will airpruned trees regrow their taproot?

Tags: trees, seedlings, roots

If I grow a strongly tap-rooted tree (such as a pecan) in an air prune bed, will the tree grow a tap root when planted out?

Answer (score 2):

According to

https://www.ncforestservice.gov/publications/techBulletins/TRB013.pdf

"Studies show that about 4-17% of container seedlings do not develop a tap or sinker root after out-planting."

It is unclear if this statistic is in reference to regular potted plants, chemical root pruning with copper, or air pruned specimens.  Also the source of that information is not cited in the article.

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to trees all you really need is just 4 inches of the tap-root

after it is cut the tap-root will just grow wider along with the main stem.

then  to reach the other spaces available the plant will branch out smaller roots which will in turn continue to grow as well